# How to find Profit between 3 different tables

Tags: mysql, sql, max, mysql-workbench

My project is about a jewelery store and i try to find the produxt with the max Profit.

I have 3 tables which gives me the info:

SALES table:

```
salesid  productid   Quantity Price
11001    13001       4        5
11002    13002       6        10
11003    13003       5        16
.
.
11012    13012       7        15
```

RETURN table:

```
salesid  productid   Quantity Price
11003    13003       1        16
11007    13007       3        12
11008    13008       3        8
```

PROCUREMENT table:

```
procurementid  productid   Quantity Price
100001         13001       10       2
100002         13002       10       2
.
. 
100012         13012       10       2
```

The profit is given from this formula:

> Profit = Quantity * Price(Sell) - Quantity * Price(Return) - Quantity * Price(Procurement)

And now here is the problem. I came up to this so far

```
select a.productid,(a.quantity*a.price-b.quantity*b.price-c.quantity*c.price) as Profit
from sales as a ,return as b ,procurement as c
where a.productid = c.productid 
GROUP BY productid
```

In this situation I don't get the correct answer.

This is because in the return table I have only 3 registers but at the other tables I have 12, so when it calculates the profit it uses the whole return table for each row of the other tables.

I tried to use `max(Profit)` but it didn't do anything.

I actually don't know how I can connect the 3 registers of the return table so that they are used only when they have to. When i tried the joins a lot of rows were null. I think that something has to be done with `OUTER JOIN` or something but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be rather new to SQL.  When giving tables aliases, try to use table abbreviations.  It makes the queries much easier to read (for example, `p` for `procurement` and `s` for sales).

Also, you need to learn proper join syntax.  However, that will not really help you here, because you need to pre-aggregate before doing the joins.  That is, get the cost, sales, and return amounts separately and then bring them together:

```
select p.productid,
       (coalesce(s.rev, 0) - coalesce(r.ret, 0) - coalesce(p.cost, 0)) as profit
from (select p.productid, SUM(quantity*price) as cost
      from procurement p
      group by p.productid
     ) p left outer join
     (select s.productid, sum(quantity*price) as rev
      from sales s
      group by s.productid
     ) s 
     on p.productid = s.productid
     (select r.productid, sum(quantity*price) as ret
      from return
      group by s.productid
     ) r
     on p.productid = r.productid;
```

This query also uses a `left outer join`.  This is important, because not all products may have sales or returns.  You don't want to lose these, just because they are lousy sellers (no sales) or supremely popular (no returns).

Comment: I agree with this poster, the product id from the procurement table should be used. you can have no sales have procurement ....

Comment: i found out this is SO REALLY HELPFULL..i am so close to the answer now but here is the problem:i can see all the productid in the column, but at the profit column i can only see the 3 registers that i have in the return table and all the others are NULL

Comment: @user2432398 . . . Fixed using a function called `coalesce()`.  When data is missing (such as returns), the value is NULL and this turns the arithmetic expression into `NULL`.  `coalesce()` instead turns the `NULL` into `0`.

Comment: the time i thought about this function i saw ur reply :) thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use a `LEFT JOIN` on your return table since it only has 3 of the products and the other tables have all 12.

```
select a.productid,
    (a.quantity*a.price-coalesce(b.quantity,0)*coalesce(b.price,0)-c.quantity*c.price) as Profit
from sales a 
    join procurement c on a.productid = c.productid 
    left join return b on a.salesid = b.salesid
group by a.productid
```

This also uses `COALESCE` to change `NULL` values to 0.

Comment: <3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3<3

Comment: @user2432398 -- np, glad I could help.  BTW -- I wasn't completely sure if you needed to use SUM -- if you only have the 12 records in your tables (a 1-1 relationship that is), then you won't need any aggregates.  If however your sales table could have multiple records per product, then look at Gordon's answer using SUM.  Kind regards.

Answer (score 0):

you want to do a left outer join of sales to returns. (you can have sales with no returns, but there should be no returns when you have no sales. )

and then you want to right outer join procurement to this comined table (because procurement does not gurantee sales, but you cant sell stuff you dont have. )

```
select c.productid, 
(a.quantity*a.price-b.quantity*b.price-c.quantity*c.price) as Profit
from (sales as a LEFT JOIN return as b ON a.productid = b.productid) 
RIGHT JOIN procurement as c ON a.productid = c.productid
where a.productid = c.productid 
GROUP BY productid
```

this should have no nulls